# Rails mailer mandrill setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mandrill

I am trying to setup email with Mandrill on development so I can test it in production.  I am new to rails and having trouble figuring out if I have to configure the 'from' (sender) email in a special.  All the guides online have not helped me.  I have set up an account with Mandrill and configured accordingly.

development.rb
    Rails.application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true


  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # change to true to allow email to be sent during development
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =
  {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 587,
    :user_name => ENV[:email],
    :password  => "ENV[:password]"
  }


end
```

mailer

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "ajn123@vt.edu"


  def contact_user(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: @message.email, subject: "Contact from AJNORTON.com").deliver
  end

end
```

Log (no email is sent, but no error is given)

```
Sent mail to ajn123@vt.edu (459.0ms)
Date: Sat, 29 Nov 2014 06:30:36 -0500
From: ajn123@vt.edu
To: ajn123@vt.edu
Message-ID: <5479ae5c53708_7ef13fce5cda9c2828447@Air.mail>
Subject: Contact from AJNORTON.com
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<div>
  <p>
    tntn
  </p>
  <p>
    ajn123@vt.edu
  </p>
  <p>
    ntntnt
  </p>
</div>


ContactMailer#contact_user: processed outbound mail in 478.3ms
```

Answer (score 1):

try to enable TLS: put an "enable_starttls_auto: true" and an "authentication: :plain" on your ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =
{
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 587,
    :user_name => ENV[:email],
    :password  => ENV[:password],
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Also, your ENV[:password] is wrong. You should't put inside quotes.

WRONG:

```
:password  => "ENV[:password]"
```

CORRECT:

```
:password  => ENV[:password]
```